# Facebook-esque (iOS) News Feed Custom UITableCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, feed

I'm creating an iOS app using Swift that will have a "News Feed" type of component to it. After doing some research it seems that the best way to do this is by using a UITableView with a custom cell design. If you look at the current Facebook iOS app, their news feed style is essentially what I'm after. I'm not 100% confident that they're not using an HTML5 framework to power that, though.

I've done up a concept image of how I'd like mine to look.

[image]

As you can see, the "content" part of the table cell will need to be "responsive" / be able to "grow" with the content. The header and footers will be static in height.

The content will also contain text and / or images, as seen below.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout

Comment: I hope you have got solution for this. Can you let me know how you managed back when you are inside some feed and there is update in some feed or new feed added.

Answer (score 0):

It seems UITableview only can be very slow, since it has to render the cells all the time during scrolling. Take a look at ComponentKit https://code.facebook.com/posts/1415586422080360/introducing-componentkit-functional-and-declarative-ui-on-ios/. 
Good luck and tell me if you find something better...

Answer (score 0):

In the data source, when you set the table cell height, couldn't you put something in there that says instead of like a static number for height, you could make it find out how much stuff the cell has to hold, then adjust the height based on that?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat 
{
    var height = getNumberOfObjects()
    height = height * 10
    return height
}
```

Something like that? I'm not sure if the syntax is exactly right.